# Xamarin.iOS - Save Checked Status in UITableView using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin

Experts,

Please see below as I have a table and want to save the checked status of the table within NSUserDefaults in Xamarin.iOS.  How would you go about saving the checked status in NSUserDefaults (data.Selected = true)?  Ideally, what I want, is after every checked cell, I want to save that value into NSUserDefaults.  Then, if the users terminate the app, the values that they selected prior to terminating the app will be loaded.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have the following TableSource class:

```
namespace Project
{
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource 
{
public readonly static string cellIdentifier = "cellID";
readonly Model _model;

    public TableSource(Model source)
    {
        _model = source;
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var value = _model[indexPath.Row];
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (cellIdentifier)   ??  new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, cellIdentifier) ;
        cell.TextLabel.Text = value.Name;
        cell.TextLabel.Font = UIFont.FromName ("Arial", 15f);
        cell.Accessory = value.Selected ? UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark : UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return _model.Count;
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView,NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.CellAt(indexPath);
        var data = _model[indexPath.Row];

        if (data.Selected)
            data.Selected = false;
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
            Toast.MakeText( data.Name.ToString() + " Not Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).SetGravity(ToastGravity.Center).Show();
        }

        else
        {
            data.Selected = true;
            cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
            Toast.MakeText( data.Name.ToString() + " Checked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).SetGravity(ToastGravity.Center).Show()

        }

        cell.Selected = false;
        tableView.ReloadData ();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: You state what you want to do, and you posted some code, but what is the problem? what is the actual question? please see [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Sorry, I edited my response above to state the question.

Answer (score 1):

Storing/fetching a boolean to/from NSUserDefaults is fairly easy:

```
// Store
bool value = data.Selected;
string key = string.Format("TableName{0}",indexPath.Row); // Some unique name
NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetBool (value, key);
// Fetch
bool checked = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.BoolForKey (key);
```

However, using NSUserDefaults for this seems a bit harsh.
Why don't you look into saving the user's selection to a JSON file in the App's Cache folder?

Comment: Thanks so much!  I did take the approach of keeping track of the selection via a JSON file.  Works perfectly.